# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el id correctamente desde esta consulta?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, foreach, blade, mongoatlas

Estoy usando MongoDB y Laravel

estoy haciendo la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
$json_datos = DB::table('items_tabla')->get();
$datos_finales= json_decode($json_datos );
```

La consulta `$json_datos` obtengo estos datos:
[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces por eso uso el `json_decode` para poder obtenerlos de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero el problema que tengo es que cuando intento mostrar en el `blade` el `_id`
me aparece un error por que el id esta dentro de otra llave, y no se como entrar para poder obtenerlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi uso el foreach en el blade:

```
@foreach ($datos_finales as $item)
   {{$item->_id}}  //error
   {{$item->imagen}} //success
@endforeach
```

agradecería la ayuda, muchas gracias!

Comment: @BetaM, que tal, si eso lo intente y me aparecía esto : `Undefined variable: oid `.
Gracias por responder.

Comment: Y si no haces el json_decode y le pasas directamente la colección a la vista?

Comment: lo que pasa es que las llaves están como String y no me reconoce en el Blade, por eso opte por `json_decode`, igual en las capturas se aprecia lo que te digo.

Comment: Porque no haces un 
$datos_finales= json_decode(json_encode($json_datos), true);
Y luego los llamas como un array  {{$item['_id']['$oid']}}

Comment: usando de referencia la primera imagen que pusiste para obtener el oid lo puede haces asi: 
$datos_finales= json_decode($json_datos );
dd($datos_finales[0]['_id']->oid);

Comment: @GerardoMarroquin, me funciona con tu forma, si gustas agrégala como respuesta para darla como la solución para mi pregunta.

Comment: @DAD Cual de las formas te funciono?

Comment: @GerardoMarroquin, la primera {{$item['_id']['$oid']}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba de esta forma, deberias poder acceder a tu array sin los stdClass

```
$datos_finales= json_decode(json_encode($json_datos), true);

@foreach ($datos_finales as $item)
    {{$item['_id']['$oid']}}
    {{$item['imagen']}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias amigo!.

Comment: De nada para eso estamos en esta comunidad :)